# React/Redux appending more data to page using button

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I am working on a react/redux application. The app renders data from an API, but only shows up to 25 items per call. I have a "Load More" button to send another call to the API to fetch the next 25 items. I have a function (getAllReviews) that pushes all the data to an array and returns the array. I then map over the array to render the data onto the page. The data appends correctly to the page, however, since the mapping occurs over the entire array, I am getting the warning: Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, only the first child will be used.

Any advice on how to avoid this warning/another way to append information to the page?

```
const ReviewTile = React.createClass({
      getInitialState() {
     return {
        page: 1,
      allReviews: []
     }
  },
    getAllReviews(){ //pushes all 25 items to allReviews array
        let reviews = this.props.reducerReview.allReviewData[0].reviewData.reviews;
        reviews.forEach(ele => {
            this.state.allReviews.push(ele)
        })
        return this.state.allReviews;
    },

  getMoreReviews(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        let page = ++this.state.page;
        this.props.postReviews(page); //returns new array with 25 items
        this.getAllReviews();
   },
    render() {
        let reviews = this.getAllReviews();
          return (
  <div>
  {
    reviews.map((review) =>
            <Review //component
              key={review.id}
              reviewBody={review.review}
            />
          )
        }

       <button 
          type="button" 
          className="btn" 
          onClick={ this.getMoreReviews }> Load More
        </button>
  </div> 

);
```

}

Comment: Are your review.id values unique? I seems like they are not. The value of the "key" attribute on your Review element should be unique such as a primary key. A possible culprit is that your getMoreReviews function is loading duplicate reviews with the same id.

Comment: Revised it to reviews.map((review, i) =>
            <Review
              key={i}

Answer (score 0):

@mleonard87's comment on your question is right in that you need to make sure the key you are using is unique. I see you commented in reply saying you switched it to be index - using index for a key in react is an antipattern (here's a post about this - https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318#.w1usaxz9j), as the index of items can change and it's not a reliable value to use for a key.

When you loop to render items, they need to have a key for react to perform properly. You can read about this in detail on their documentation - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html

I'm surprised your IDs aren't unique! An ID is generally meant to be a unique identifier. Is there any way you can fix this to make them unique? Or is there another value on the review objects that will be reliably unique per review?